# React Native Expo Firebase v9.9.x Firestore add value to array

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, expo

My database looks like this:

- collection id: "my-collection"
- each user gets a document which name is user id
- each document consist out of one array "data" which holds maps:

```js
data: [{"prop1" : "1", "prop2" : "2"}, {"prop1" : "4", "prop2" : "1"}]
```

I can create the document with

```js
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Class component that wraps my code...
const firestoreDb = getFirestore();
const user = getAuth().currentUser;
const document = doc(firestoreDb, "my-collection", user.uid);

setDoc(document, {
  data: []
}).then(() => console.log("Created user document.").catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How can I add elements to the `data` array? I know there exists a function `updateDoc`, but I don't know how to use it and cannot find any documentation.

Please note that in this version the `firestore.collection()` method does not exist.

Comment: So you are trying to push new objects to that data array? Do you have the V8 namespaced syntax of the same if written before?

Comment: Docs on updating a doc, with code sample in v9 of the JavaScript SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_8 --- Docs for adding items to an array with v9 sample: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_11

Comment: the data:[ ] that is in the setDoc method, you have to put only data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers the following is a solution:

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { arrayUnion, updateDoc, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firestoreDb = getFirestore();
const user = getAuth().currentUser;
const document = doc(firestoreDb, "my-collection", user.uid);
updateDoc(document, { data: arrayUnion({"prop1": "5", "prop2", "6"}) })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Updated document");
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```